# Hover on an element and show another another element

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseevent, mouseover

I'm making a small test about hover action.
For exam I have 2 elements like this

```
<body>
<input type ='button' value ='hover this' class='hover_button'>
<div class='hover_div' style='display :none' >Some text here</div>
</body>
```

(For some reason, I can't let the div as child of button or something close, button just a test, we can have many alter elements here)

Yes, when we hover on the button, the div will be shown, but I want when we blur on the button, and take focus on the div, the div still be shown as soon as we blur on this div.
I tried with this code :
But it doesn't working properly:

```
$(button).hover(function(e)
    {

         e.preventDefault();
         //alert('a');
         var top = parseInt($(button).css('top'));
         var left = parseInt($(button).css('left'));

         $(div).css({top : top, left : left}).show();
         //e.stopPropagation();

    },function(e)
    {
        $(div).fadeOut(600);
    })

    $(div).hover(function(e)
    {
        //e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).show();
    },function(e)
    {
        $(this).hide();
    })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method of jQuery to stop the current animation. Then when you hover over the div you can show the div (so it isn't half faded).

Example : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/A8RM2/2/)

```
var button = $('.hover_button');
var div = $('.hover_div');

$(button).hover(function(e) {    
    var top = parseInt($(button).css('top'));
    var left = parseInt($(button).css('left'));

    $(div).css({top : top, left : left}).show();
},function(e) {
    $(div).fadeOut(600);
});

$(div).hover(function(e) {
    $(this).stop().show();
},function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Note that we now use `$(this).stop().show();` so that we stop the current animation before we show the div, so it stops the fadeOut.

Comment: Very cool, thank so much, but can you explain a little about it for me.

Comment: I think we can made it more brief, I mean, we don't need to use anim variable, 
$(div).hover(function(e) {
    
    $(this).stop().show();
},function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
});
THanks

Comment: Good thinking, I'll update my answer to remove the anim variable.

Answer (score 1):

Like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.hover_button').hover(function () {
        var $target = $('div');
        clearTimeout($target.data('hoverTimer'));
        var top = parseInt($(this).css('top'));
        var left = parseInt($(this).css('left'));

        $('div').css({
            top: top,
            left: left
        }).show();
    }, function () {
        var $target = $('div');
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $target.hide();
        }, 200);
        $target.data('hoverTimer', timer);
    });

    $('div').hover(function () {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimer'));
    }, function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y6LyN/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but your button selector is wrong :)  use

```
$('input[type=button]')
```

instead of

```
 $('button')
```

Demo Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6AGGr/

Comment: thank for you reply but I use button like a variable
var button = ".hover_button";
then we can use 
$(button) :)